# Multiply-subtract in SSE

Tags: c, vectorization, sse

I am vectorizing a piece of code and at some point I have the following setup:

```
register m128 a = { 99,99,99,99,99,99,99,99 }
register m128 b = { 100,50,119,30,99,40,50,20 }
```

I am currently packing `short`s in these registers, which is why I have 8 values per register. What I would like to do is subtract the i'th element in `b` with the corresponding value in `a` if the i'th value of `b` is greater than or equal to the value in `a` (In this case, `a` is filled with the constant 99 ). To this end, I first use a greater than or equal to operation between `b` and `a`, which yields, for this example:

```
register m128 c = { 1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0 }
```

To complete the operation, I'd like to use the multiply-and-subtract, i.e. to store in `b` the operation `b -= a*c`. The result would then be:

```
b = { 1,50,20,30,0,40,50,20 }
```

Is there any operation that does such thing? What I found were fused operations for Haswell, but I am currently working on Sandy-Bridge. Also, if someone has a better idea to do this, please let me know (e.g. I could do a logical subtract: if 1 in `c` then I subtract, nothing otherwise.

Comment: Just to clarify, should your operation be `b -= a*c`, to perform the appropriate subtraction?

Answer (score 4):

You essentially want an SSE version of this code, right?

```
if (b >= a)
    t = b-a
else
    t = b
b = t
```

Since we want to avoid conditionals for the the SSE version so we can get rid of the control flow like this (note that the mask is inverted):

```
uint16_t mask = (b>=a)-1
uint16_t tmp = b-a;
uint16_t d = (b & mask) | (tmp & ~mask)
b = d
```

I've checked the `_mm_cmpgt_epi16` intrinsic and it has a nice property in that it returns either `0x0000` for false or `0xFFFF` for true, instead of a single bit 0 or 1 (thereby eliminating the need for the first subtraction). Therefore our SSE version might look like this.

```
__m128i mask = _mm_cmpgt_epi16 (b, a)
__m128i tmp = _mm_sub_epi16 (b, a)
__m128 d = _mm_or_ps (_mm_and_ps (mask, tmp), _mm_andnot_ps (mask, b))
```

**EDIT**: harold has mentioned a far less complicated answer. The above solution might be helpful if you need to modify the *else* part of the *if/else*.

```
uint16_t mask = ~( (b>=a)-1 )
uint16_t tmp = a & mask
b = b - tmp
```

the SSE code will be

```
__m128i mask = _mm_cmpgt_epi16 (b, a)
__m128i t = _mm_sub_epi16 (b, _mm_and_si128 (mask, a))
```

Comment: Except that you used `d` where I have `c`, yes. Your operation `b = d` is not needed in my case, because I am ok with out-place operations. I think you don't want to do `m = (b>=a)-1` but `m = (b>=a)`, right?

Comment: No. Your `c` is my `m` (for mask). The `d` variable is just to make it more readable. Also, the `m = (b>=a)-1` is correct because then we convert a single bit mask (0 or 1) to an 8-bit mask (0000000 or 11111111) which we need for the next line.

Comment: @a3mlord I've just taken a closer look at the `mm_cmpgt` intrinsic. It actually does return either 0x00 or 0xFF so on second thought we won't need the -1, but we will have to change the order of the and operators. I will edit my post now...

Comment: @a3mlord I don't think that will work. At the end of this operation `c` will contain `b-a` in parts and `0` in the rest. You need a **logical or** operation to get around this. Both my scalar and SSE code leverage this.

Comment: @a3mlord I don't think that will work either. You are logical ORing the `b` variable unconditionally. You _only_ want it to take affect when `b<a`. If you look at my example answer, I use a mask and then the inverse of the same mask. That way we guarantee that one side of the OR statement will evaluate to `0` and therefore not affect the opposite side.

Comment: Why so complicated? You don't have to blend the subtracted and the unsubtracted thing, you can just mask away the subtrahend and subtract zero from all the unaffected elements.

Comment: Well not like that, just use bitwise AND, mul-high doesn't make a lot of sense here

Comment: @harald Agreed again, thanks.. I keep forgetting that SSE compares return extended bitmasks rather than the single bit of a scalar compare.

Comment: @hayesti The latest version (suggested by @harold) was what I was looking for. BTW, forgot about what I said before: I was thinking SSE-wise. However, I have one question. If you have two SSE registers `a = 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1` and `b = 50 50 50 50 50 50 50 50`, mm_add (a,b) will return `0 0 0 0 50 50 50 50` ? So add returns the biggest value?

Comment: @a3mlord Do you mean `add` or `and`? Anyway, if you want the maximum of two vectors, it's better to use: `__m128i _mm_max_epi16 (__m128i a, __m128i b)`

Comment: @hayesti I meant AND, sorry. What would be the answer? Thanks

Comment: @a3mlord I'm not sure what you're asking, sorry. In the case you mention, `mm_add` will return `0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1`. If you want to find the maximum between `a` and `b` you can use `mm_max`.

Comment: @hayesti In the latest code you have, mask might have the value `1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0` in my example, right? Then, you do an ADD between `mask` and `a` (in my example `99 99 99 99 99 99 99 99`). So ADD between 1 and 99 returns 99, right?

Comment: @a3mlord Right, except that the mask should be `0xFFFF, 0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0x0000, 0xFFFF, 0x0000, 0x0000, 0x0000` instead of `1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0`. This will be generated from `_mm_cmpgt_epi16 ` so everything is sound.

Comment: I just noticed my proposed edit to clarify some things got rejected.  http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8664046.  I forgot that reviewers would see the proposed edit probably before you got around to it.  Anyway,  ` ~( (b>=a)-1 )` is gratuitously complex and hard to read.  `b>=a ? 0xFFFF : 0` would be much easier.  Also, use the `si128` logicals, not `ps`.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, if your inputs are unsigned, you can calculate

```
b = min(b, b-a);
```

This works, because if `a>b` then `b-a` wraps around and is guaranteed to result in a bigger value than `b`. For `a<=b` you will always get a value between `0` and `b` inclusive.

```
b = _mm_min_epu16(b, _mm_sub_epi16(b,a));
```

The required `_mm_min_epu16` requires SSE4.1 or later (`_mm_min_epu8` would require only SSE2).

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `b` to `c`, subtract `a` from `c`, perform an arithmetic shift right by 15 positions in the 16 bit values, complement the value of `c`, mask `c` with `a`, and finally subtract `c` from `b`.

I'm not familiar for the intrinsics syntax, but the steps are:

```
register m128 c = b;
c -= a;
c >>= 15;
c = ~c;
c &= a;
b -= c;
```

here is an alternative with fewer steps:

```
register m128 c = compare_ge(b, a);
c = -c;
c &= a;
b -= c;
```